# How to move capital letters in front without using any regular expression/ built in function such as split,join,indexOf etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

```
function moveCapLetter(moveCap) {
  let upr = /[A-Z]/g;
  let ul = moveCap.match(upr);

  for (let i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
    let m = moveCap.length;
    let indx = moveCap.indexOf(ul[i]);
    moveCap =
      moveCap.substring(0, indx) + moveCap.substring(indx + 1, moveCap.length);
  }
  moveCap = ul.join("") + moveCap;
  return moveCap;
}
```

Comment: why? Why would you not make use of built in functions, are you trying to re write an entire language?

Comment: It was our prof. He is challenging us

Answer (score 0):

The only way I come up with is to test whether it is `uppercase` or `lowercase` after converting it into `uppercase` using `toUpperCase`(else how can we check) and concat separately.

```js
function moveCapLetter(str) {
  let upper = "",
    lower = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    if (str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase()) {
      upper += str[i];
    } else lower += str[i];
  }

  return (upper += lower);
}

const result = moveCapLetter("eNviRonMEnT");
console.log(result);
```